# using Node-mavlink to control a drone, but altitude does not change when using setPosition command

Tags: node.js, mavlink, mission-planner

I have two drones running on different Pixhawk systems, one is running on an old pixhawk 1 and the second is running on a new pixhawk 4 orange cube.
I am using node-mavlink library created by ardupilot:[library](https://github.com/ArduPilot/node-mavlink), I want to send the drones on simple missions using the Guided fligth mode.
I have encountered a very peculiar issue that I can't seem to manage to solve, the pixhawk 1 system works well with the commands I am trying to run, but the pixhawk 4 system refuses to update its altitude when using the set_position_target_global_int.
If i use only the .alt parameter, it does not move at all, and if I add other parameters such as long/lat or yaw, those change according to what I've provided, but the altitude does not change no matter what. The pixhawk 1 version works very well. I have compared their parameters using Mission Planner's full parameter list, and other than PID, they are the same. my code is running on V1 protocol, and my friend is working now on changing to V2 to test it. I would really appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on why this issue is occuring, if you are familiar with it or have any suggestions.
my altitude change command:

```
const alt = new common.SetPositionTargetGlobalInt(1, 1); 
alt.coordinateFrame = 6; //
alt.typeMask = 4088;
alt.lonInt = current_long; 
alt.latInt = current_lat; 
alt.alt = altitude; 
alt.yaw = yaw_;
const buffer6 = protocol.serialize(alt, myMAV.sequence); //myMAV.sequence
console.log(buffer6.toString('hex'));
port.send(buffer6, 0, buffer6.length, 10001, "192.168.1.254", (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log("changing altitude");
    }
});
```

basic pixhawk connection configuration:

```
var mavlink = require('mavlink');
var myMAV = new mavlink(1,1,"v1.0",["common", "ardupilotmega"]);
const { app,BrowserWindow,screen,ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
const fs = require('fs')
let openAPP = require('child_process').exec
const { setTimeout } = require('timers');
const { Console } = require('console');
var dgram = require('dgram');
const { common, MavLinkProtocolV1 } = require('node-mavlink');
const protocol = new MavLinkProtocolV1();
var port = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
```

I could provide more code fragments if needed, but i do not know what is relevent and what is not and i do not want to clutter this page, so please ask if you think something is missing.
would appreciate any help on this

comparing the paramtere tree showed that the only difference in params betweent he pixhawks is the PID of the drone they are on, they are running on the same mavlink version which is 4.37, both are responding well the arm,takeoff,land, change position commands well, but the drone running pixhawk 4 just ignore the altitude change in the position command.